# intersection of search (in diff. fields) - Lucene

Tags: search, lucene, field, intersection

I tried following in Lucene 6.2.1:

I have different fields `A`,`B`,`C`,`D`,`E` and I make for every field a different `searchquery`.

Then I want to make a intersection. Show it, when the result is everywhere true.

Someone told me to try this with `Booleanquery`. So this is my approach:

```
IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(index)));
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();

BufferedReader in = null;
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

QueryParser parser1 = new QueryParser("A", analyzer);// i have 5 different QueryParser
Query qPersonen = parser1.parse("searchstring"); // i have also 5 Queries
booleanQuery.add(qPersonen, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

TotalHitCountCollector collector = new TotalHitCountCollector();
TopDocs results = searcher.search(booleanQuery.build(), 100);

ScoreDoc[] hits = results.scoreDocs;
int numTotalHits = results.totalHits;
System.out.println("Results: " + numTotalHits);
```

Why isn't it working? What could be the fault? It always returns no results :(

Comment: what is your question? is the approach not working ?

Comment: why don't you get instance of `BooleanQuery` ?

Answer (score 0):

As I see your code, It seems that you didn't get instance of `BooleanQuery`. Since lucene 5, the boolean query's API has been changed. Try the following:

```
QueryParser parser1 = new QueryParser("A", analyzer);// i have 5 different QueryParser
Query qPersonen = parser1.parse("searchstring"); // i have also 5 Queries
BooleanQuery.Builder bq = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
bq.add(new BooleanClause(aPersonen, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));
```

Hope this will work for you :)